# How can I batch delete all files of a certain type in a folder newer than a certain date on Windows?

Tags: windows, batch

So Google Music decided to download about half of my uploaded music library to my local music library when I told it to download my purchased music, so now I have a bunch of MP3s I need to delete automatically.

Can I get any help here? I'm not so great with batch script.

Comment: Have to know which windows OS?    I would address this as a selection problem like this by using "Search" , "Sort" , "Select" not having to batch anything. - - - - "Search" *.mp3 , there is every MP3. Add advanced search items like Date.  Once you get a trimmed down enough "Search" then "Sort" use the Columns (size, Date modified date created, type) to "Sort", then Select the top item, hold the shift key, Select the last item needed to delete, and delete away. Search Sort Select.

Comment: I had forgotten I could do all of that in search. I tinkered around a bit with it and eventually got the selection I needed. I'll mark Sathya's comment as the answer since it would definitely work with a bit of tinkering using the syntax page, probably a bit more efficiently and universally as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `forfiles`

```
forfiles /p g:\music /d -30 /c "cmd /c del @file"
```

This will delete any file older than 30 days.

Read about forfiles syntax [here](http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html)

If it's not there in your system, download forfiles from MSFT's [Reskit ftp](ftp://ftp.microsoft.com/ResKit/y2kfix/x86/)

Answer (score 1):

For another command script way to do this, using [JP Software's TCC/LE](http://jpsoft.com./tccle_cmd_replacement.html), simply use [date ranges](http://jpsoft.com./help/dateranges.htm) and the `del` command:

```
del /[d2011-12-19] *.mp3
```

Yes, you can do the last 30 days, too:

```
del /[d-30] *.mp3
```

### Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2003,2007). [*Performing some commonly desired tasks with JP Software's command interpreters.*](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/common-tasks-with-jpsoft-clis.html). Frequently Given Answers.