# How to mass remove symbolic links in Windows (among regular files that share similar name in many folders)?

Tags: command-line, symbolic-link, file-types, file-filter

Is there any way to quickly remove many symbolic links in many folders that contains many other files? E.g some command in command prompt (be able to delete all slink created from day XX for example)?

Remove all objects that are **symbolic link**, all other objects remain. Now I only navigate folder by folder, manually selecting them in Windows Explorer (rearrange all items by size, and symbolic links size 0KB, and shift key select all --> del) and remove slowly, maybe sometime mistake sl with another 0KB files. My younger bro drag & drop a lot of files with right click (Link Shell Extension Copyright (C) 1999 - 2008 by Hermann Schinagl already installed in PC, integrated into Windows Explorer) and he pick drop as *symbolic link*, it all became garbage.

Answer (score 10):

This is similar to JdeBP's answer, but it doesn't require any external software:

```
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %a IN (`DIR /a:l /s /b "C:\dir\with\symlinks"`) DO RMDIR "%a"
```

When used in a script, substitute `%a` with `%%a`.

Comment: I tried FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%a IN (`DIR /a:l /s /b "D:\"`) DO RMDIR "%%a". I get %%a was unexpected at this time.

Comment: When typed directly into the command line, substitute `%%a` with `%a`. `%%a` is for use in a batch file, as it says in the output of `for /?`. I'll update my answer to include this info.

Comment: Note this only works for folder symlinks. For file symlinks change rmdir to del

Answer (score 5):

### Using the SFUA utility toolkit:

Finding symbolic links can be done the same ways as [finding hard links](https://superuser.com/a/366748/38062): using the `find` command that is in Microsoft's [SFUA utility toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=93FF2201-325E-487F-A398-EFDE5758C47F), that runs in the [Subsystem for Unix-based Applications](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc772343.aspx):

```
find . -type l|xargs rm --
```

### Using [JP Software's TCC/LE](http://jpsoft.com./tccle_cmd_replacement.html):

This is a simple exercise in the use of [attribute switches](http://jpsoft.com./help/attrswitch.htm) and the ordinary [`del` command](http://jpsoft.com./help/del.htm):

```
del /a:l *
```

You can, of course, use the `/s`, `/p`, and other options to the `del` command.  And you can preview what would be deleted either by using `del`'s `/n` option or simply by substituting `dir` for `del`.

## Caveat

Both of these actually find *reparse points*.  Symbolic links are *but one form* of reparse points.  If you have others, such as junctions, you'll have to be careful about what parts of your directory tree you apply these commands to.  [Using date ranges to only delete files with recent creation dates](https://superuser.com/a/371101/38062) (`/[dc…]`) might be profitable as well.

Comment: The TCC/LE version doesn't seem to work with junctions, because /s descends *into* junctions, rather than *considering them to delete*.  /nj will stop that, but doesn't seem to solve the problem.

The following seems to work, even though del claims to have deleted nothing:

del /a:l /s /e /l *

As a useful helper, this will list all such files:

dir /a:l /s /nj /k /m

so you can see if it worked.

-Robin

Comment: This failed to delete the reparse points in my directory tree, but did allow me to find them (substituing `dir` for `del`) for deletion via the Windows File Explorer.